# Getting socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, tomcat, socket.io

I'm really new into node.js , and I will be really happy if anybody will be able to help me.

I have a web app , on tomcat , so the access port I work with is 8080. 
On one of my html pages, the functionality I am trying to achieve is that when I click a specific button , I would like to send a notification to anybody who access this page , and then these users would perform a relevant action. 
So actually, I want to use node.js as a notification server, using socket.io , so that's what I have done on the server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("A new connection was opened");

  socket.on('status change', function(data) {
   console.log('status has changed to ' + data);
        io.sockets.emit('set new status', data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    io.emit('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

On client side, I configured on my html page, which is located on my tomcat server , I did the following(I just put some relevant parts from my html):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');
    socket.on('set new status', function(data){
        myFunction();
    });
 $("#button").click(function()
    {
        socket.emit('status change', isOn);
    });
</script>
```

So, when I open my html page, I get the following and error on:
GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js
And of course, this was accessible if my web app was running on port 3000.

How can I make it working?! 
I am sure I am missing something really stupid, and spend hours for nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` is using the port number from the page URL which is 3000 and goes to your tomcat server which does not have that file in order to serve it.  You can either put that file on your tomcat server or you could try putting the webSocket port into the script tag: `<script src="http://whatever.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` so that the socket.io server will serve the file.  Either could work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your tomcat server isn't redirecting to the Node.js server for the socket.io library.  I'm no tomcat expert, so I'll link https://serverfault.com/questions/55427/redirecting-tomcat-requests-to-another-host as a possible place to look for a solution.

What you want to do is set it up so when the request comes in to tomcat for /socket.io/socket.io.js it forwards to :3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

You will need to do this for any other assets that need to be served as well.  Might be worth setting up a sub-folder to serve from.

The other thing you could do is just serve the entire content from Node.js itself.

We use Hapi and I can point you to a few chat applications built with it, or look at the Socket.io page itself for a full Node implementation of a chat application.  If your using Express or want to go Node only then there are resources out there, but I don't have them ready at hand :D